How can I analyze the anatomy of a humanoid species to create sounds for their language?
I am making a constructed language for a vespid-humanoid species, Ictuk. I recently stumbled upon PIE and their usage of consonant sonority in their roots, which made a lot of sense with how the human voice works. However, I was looking to do a similar technique for Ictuk, which as a species with a vespidae anatomy have less versatility than the human voice.
My question is, what are some strategies I can use to find potential sounds for a humanoid species, mainly in anatomy?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The phonemes of human languages are not limited by the anatomy of the human phonatory apparatus. For example, look at the International Phonetic Alphabet chart of pulmonic consonants; the grayed cells are physically impossible, but note how many non-grayed cells are left blank because no language uses that sound. (And several of the sounds which do have symbols are not actually used in human languages -- the symbols were assigned because it was thought that surely we will find a language using that sound.)

@AlexP It’s a bit disingenuous to say that the phonemic inventory of human languages is not limited by human physiology. Physiological limitations do define a superset of actually observed phonemes, but that doesn’t mean that physiology doesn’t limit things, just that there are other limits in play as well.

@AustinHemmelgarn: Hmm. Maybe it would be better to say that no human language uses anywhere near the entire phonemic space which would be allowed by human anatomy, and that not even the sum total of all known human languages comes close?

This is really more appropriate on conlang.stackexchange.com than here.

Such question appear from time to time on this site, and they always make me wonder why on Earth would anybody care? Supposing that somebody could actually provide an answer, how could a writer use that answer?
First of all, let's consider how the phonemes and phones of a human language are described. They are not described in physical terms; they are described in terms of the human phonatory apparatus.

For example, /p/ is a voiceless bilabial plosive.
It is a plosive, meaning that its manner of articulation is occlusive, meaning that the airflow is temporarily blocked; other manners of articulation include nasal, fricative, affricate and so on.
Its place of articulation is bilabial, meaning it is articulated with the lips, and not for example coronal, dorsal and so on.
Its phonation is voiceless, meaning that the vocal chords do not vibrate when pronouncing it; the opposite is voiced.
In some languages, such as English, the phoneme /p/ is actually pronounced by native speakers as an apirated voiceless bilabial plosive [pʰ] in the onset of a stressed syllable. But English speakers do not distinguish [p] and [pʰ]; they are allophones, and many if not most people who speak English as a second language do not produce this allophone. In other languages, such as (Ancient) Greek, /p/ and /pʰ/ are distinct phonemes, written <π> and <φ> respectively.

Note that this description of the phoneme /p/ refers exclusively to features of the human phonatory apparatus and does not tell anything about the physical sound.
Yes, there do exist physical description of English (or French, or German, or Mandarin, or whatever) phonemes, but those are very highly specialized pieces of knowledge, which are mostly of use to people who work in automated speech recognition. (In automated speech generation they rarely care about physical descriptions and simply use samples of actual human voices.)


Coming back to the question about what sounds an animal with a completely non-human anatomy could make, there are only two possibilities:

Either they can make human language sounds, possibly using an entirely different way of making them. For example, parrots can produce all the sounds of human languages, but they produce them in a totally different way compared to how humans produce them.
In this case, just use the ordinary letters to write ordinary sounds. Problem solved.

Or else they make completely different sounds.
In this case, just map the ordinary letters to alien sounds. Sounds which can be sustained continuously and can form the nucleus of syllables get vowel letters, for example mapping the human front-to-back order <i>—<e>—<a>—<o>—<u> to some pertinent order in the alien speech. Sounds which can be pronounced continuously but cannot be the nucleus of a syllable get letters for continuant consonants such as <f>—<h>—<s>—<v>—<z>. Use the letters for sonorants <l>—<m>—<n>—<r> for sounds which can fill both roles. Use letters for occlusives <b>—<c>—<d>—<g>—<k>—<p>—<q>—<t> for sounds which cannot be sustained continuously.
As for how this sounds sound, use your imagination. Maybe their vowels sounds like buzzings; maybe their continuants sounds like rustlings; maybe their occlusives sound like clicks or bangs. Or in some other way.

Skizt! Knurg pren klamt? said the vespid team leader, raising their topmost appendages in a vaguely interrogative manner, the buzzing hum of the words piercing neatly though the constant din of the workshop. Wait! Where are you taking that?



My point is that there is no way to convey a physical description of really truely alien sounds except in a very technical paper, full of figures and incomprehensible acoustics jargon. In a work of fiction only a general imprecise description of the feel of the language can be conveyed, and it is therefore completely useless to get a real technical answer to the question of how the alien sounds really sound.
But what happens if the alien language is to be used in a movie, or in a game, where the language is expected to be heard?
Unlike parrots, who can make any sound they can hear, we humans have severe physical limitations and can only make human sounds. If there will be a need to provide the alien language with a physical realization, then the way to do it is to employ a specialist who will develop believable samples for the alien phonemes based on the fuzzy written descriptions. The alien sounds will then be dubbed in post-production.

I suppose I am looking a little too deep into it, at least for its use case. Thanks!

This answer comes with the big caveat that the OP is producing a written piece and not a screenplay, videogame, or other creative work in which the aliens may have an actual spoken sound to consider.  If this is going into a TV/Movie script then detailed phonetic keys can be important to make sure all the vespid actors are saying the same words the same ways: We've all seen episodes where two actors talk in a conlang and clearly pronounce the same word very differently breaking the illusion of continuity.

@Nosajimiki: Humans cannot make non-human sounds. (Unlike parrots, who can make any sound they can hear, we humans have severe physical limitations.) If there will be a need to provide the alien language with a physical realization, then the way to do it is to employ a specialist who will develop believable samples for the alien phonemes based on the fuzzy written descriptions. The alien sounds will be dubbed in post-production.

@AlexP The main differentiator is how well they imitate any sound they hear. Parrots have nothing better to do, and still, it takes them years to learn one sound. Humans, on the other hand, love to create onomatopoeia for various animals, and can learn it in seconds. Also, if you spent a year trying to imitate a dog’s bark 24/7, you would probably get pretty good at it, maybe better than a parrot.

@WhatsYourIQ192: No, that's not the case. Birds and humans produce sounds in fundamentally different way. The way the avian phonatory apparatus works is in many ways similar to a loudspeaker -- they induce controlled vibrations in a membrane. Some species of birds have very good control over this mechanism, and they can reproduce just about any sound, exactly how a loudspeaker can. On the other hand, the mechanism humans (and mammals in general) use, which is based on inducing vibrations in a column of air and then modifying it, is much more limited in output possibilities.

@WhatsYourIQ192: Here is an amazing example recorded in the wild.

@AlexP: Thats amazing. Must've lead to quite some fairy tales about invisible men in the forest in its time...

@AlexP Mammals have a larynx, or two flaps that move in and out. When air is passed between them, they vibrate, and by changing their separation, we can created different sounds. We also have very versatile mouths and throats, allowing us to further modulate the sounds. So you are right in that sense. However, birds have a syrinx, which is a section where the trachea forms. On each fork, there are two membranes, one on the inside and one on the outside. By controlling the tension of those membranes, different sounds can be created. Birds cannot modulate their sounds as much as humans.

So, as you can see, both birds and humans produce sound by modulation. The difference between humans and avians is how they create their sounds. Basically, if a bird had a larynx, it would not be able to create the same sounds, because even the lowest voice would still not be sufficient to make all the sounds that humans create. Size still affects the pitch of sounds created by a bird, hence why budgies sound higher than parrots, but the pitch is lower by default.

On message 1, there is a typo. It should say “the syrinx is a specialized section of the throat where the trachea forks”

Not to mention that phonemes can't even completely describe all human languages properly. Cantonese, for example, distinguishes between pitch as well.

You can't judge a book by its cover
The shape of a creature's outward anatomy has way less to do with the kinds of sounds it can make than the shape of its internal voicebox.  Many birds for example have none of the flexible mouth bits that humans have which would make you think that they have a more limited vocal range, but they have a much larger vocal range because their voice boxes are basically biological speakers giving them the ability to reproduce virtually any sound including human speech.
As such, your Ictuk could either be very limited in their phonetics with everything they say being just some variation of a buzzing or chittering noise, or it could include every phoneme used in every human language plus a bunch of extra ones just for good measure.  As such this becomes purely a matter of author's choice.

Vespids do not produce noise like the average animal. Rather, they tend to utilize chemical communication. They can use different pheromones to communicate different things. This would be a very interesting conlang to impliment, and plus, you could describe it very simply.
Other methods of communication include stridulation and the buzzing of the wings. Stridulation is the rubbing of body parts together. You could even throw on a guiro-like part that makes different sounds depending on which section is used. I believe the buzzing of the wings is self-explanatory.
An example would be: “The troop leader produced a pungent pheromone and rubbed his forelimbs together, creating a high pitched buzzing. The soldiers knew it was time to attack.”

Also some excellent ideas. I like the uniqueness of the pheromones, though it might be a bit tricky to implement on paper (I'm sure I'd find some janky over-engineered way though). Thanks!

Yeah, that was concerning when I made the answer. Maybe, if it’s not in violation of how you want the story to work, you can use English dialogue to portray what they are saying, and you can use the pheromones and buzzing occasionally, to add emphasis or something. That way it doesn’t lose its novelty, but you can also still show that that is how they speak. Hello games did a similar thing with the Gek in no man’s sky, and I think it turned out pretty well (although the Gek technically speak the Gek language and use “geknip,” a glorified scent packet, to show their emotions)

That's fair. I'm likely to incorporate that into my book for when I need to use it.

The Children's trilogy by A. Tchaikovsky has an interesting part about  interspecies language and communication ... Including chemical and visual (skin chromatophores) messages. Worth reading.

If your species is actually vespid, they would not be making most of the sounds with their mouths/mandibles, but with their wings, legs etc.
So as long as you want them to be actually vespid, you are stuck with them making buzzing sounds of different pitch, essentially a wordless song not a language with a vocabulary.
But the neat thing here is that since insectoid beings do not use their mouths to make sounds, they are not limited to just one sound aparatus and can achieve multi-layered polyphonics. Every Vespid is a one-wasp orcestra of sounds, which can convey information without using the structure of a verbal language.
The closest analogy I can think of would be if someone tried to use Scottish bagpipes to send a message in Morse Code, except each individual pipe of the bagpipes would produce a different line of code, which might, or might not make a coherent whole with the rest. This would allow a vespid to hold several different conversations simultaneously.

That I actually don't mind as a concept. It'd be a fun twist compared to my initial attempts of making latin-esque grammar and structure. Thanks!

Due to the way that attention and auditory processing works, and the trade-off of bandwidth vs parallelism, it's unlikely that they would speak in multiple concurrent binary streams, but rather in a series of chords in which each represent a unique  phoneme. If they speak in chords, then their words become much more information dense allowing them to speak faster which is often more helpful for survival than being able to have many slow conversations at once.
